# C#, ODBC, Sql Server and xml data type

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml, odbc

I have a sql server stored procedure (sql server 2005) that returns XML data through output parameter.
To connect to this database preferred option is System DSN and therefore I am using ODBC classes - ODBCConnection, ODBCCommand. Problem is no matter what data type I use, NChar, char, Text, NText, VarChar, NVarChar, I always get the same error when I call ODBCCommand::ExecuteNonQuery:

"Data type 0x63 is a deprecated large object, or LOB, but is marked as output parameter.  Deprecated types are not supported as output parameters.  Use current large object types instead."

I am calling the stored procedure as below:

```
     OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("{CALL FetchTasks(?)}", conn);
     cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

     OdbcParameter param1 = new OdbcParameter();
     param1.ParameterName = "@TaskXML";
     param1.OdbcType = OdbcType.Text; //I have tried nchar, char, text, ntext
     param1.Size = 2048;
     param1.Value = "<Root></Root>";
     param1.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
     cmd.Parameters.Add(param1);

     cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Is there anyway I can make it work?

Thanks in advance
-Neel.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you need to check the data type of table column which returns xml data whether its data type is xml or other? It depends on that.

Comment: The xml is created on the fly and the parameter for the stored procedure shows as Text as datatype for the parameter when I connect through server explorer in visual studio and I tried with Text but I get same error..

Comment: I think you need to convert it to the Text(System.String) & vice-versa while passing & retrieving respectively. Need to check.